# What are Token Extensions in Solana?

Tags: anchor, spl-token, rust, token-2022, token-extensions

I hear that solana token extensions are coming soon. A cursory search results in this: https://solana.com/solutions/token-extensions

Is this the same as solana SPL-2022?

What are the big differences between the new changes and the current SPL standard?

Are the current SPL standards upgradeable to the new extensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Token extensions is the new name for Token22 basically.

Its backwards compatible but its a new program and enables a bunch of new functionality like transfer hooks, native meta data, confidential transfers etc.
It will take a while until all wallets and exchanges support transfer hooks and the new meta data probably.
Also new meta data standards could evolve out of this, especially for games and on chain data. Its gonna be an interesting time. :)

Here you can find a nice list of all the currently new extensions and what they do:
https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions

Comment: got it, so essentially it is like V2 of SPL? I'm planning on deploying some SPL tokens so not sure if it makes sense waiting for V2, or just making a custom program that can be upgraded to include token22 logic?

Comment: Yes. Full adoption will probably take a while, but worth looking into already for sure!